# Prevent calling event for added class with jquery

Tags: jquery

**Here is my jquery code:**

```
$(function () {
    $('.gridster li.gs-closed').on('click', function () {
        var ulCurrentHgt = $('.gridster ul').height();
        var ulNewHgt = ulCurrentHgt + 409;
        $('.gridster > ul').height(ulNewHgt);
        $(this).find('form').slideDown();
        $(this).removeClass('gs-closed').addClass('gs-openedx');
    });

    $(document).on('click', "li.gs-opened", function () {
        var ulCurrentHgt = $('.gridster ul').height();
        var ulNewHgt = ulCurrentHgt - 409;
        $('.gridster > ul').height(ulNewHgt);

        $(this).find('form').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('gs-opened').addClass('gs-closed');
    });
})
```

**Here is the html:**

As you see when I click the `li.gs-closed`, I am adding the class `gs-opened`. Later I have some other click handler for the `gs-opened` class. But, when I am clicking the `li.gs-closed`, it's adding the class `gs-opened` and also calling the `$(document).on('click', "li.gs-opened", function()` event, which is not supposed to be called yet. How can I prevent this?

Comment: your are adding class ...X -->  $(this).removeClass('gs-closed').addClass('gs-openedx');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the class does not remove the event handler that is already bound to the element.

What you really need to do is attach one single event handler, and create some sort of toggling functionality within that handler:

```
$(function () {
    $('.gridster li').on('click', function () {
        var ulCurrentHgt = $('.gridster ul').height(),
            open         = $(this).data('open'),
            added        = open ? -409 : 409,
            ulNewHgt     = ulCurrentHgt + (added);

        $('.gridster > ul').height(ulNewHgt);
        $(this).find('form')[open ? 'slideUp':'slideDown']();

        $(this).data('open', !open);
    });
});
```

You could also delegate the first event handler :

```
$(document).on('click', "li.gs-closed", function (event) { ...
```

to make it work with dynamically added and removed classes.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use a separate class for attaching event. Because removing class will not remove already attached event on that element. You can use a flag to decide whch class to add and remove.